# Help with DevDemon Updater 3.3.0 giving PHP error with php 5.6

Tags: devdemon-updater

If I run DevDemon Updater 3.3.0 on EE 2.10.1 and set php version to 5.6 I get this block of errors.

If I uninstall DevDemon Updater 3.3.0, or if I set php back to 5.5 the errors go away.

Grateful for any advice on what to do about this.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: Non-static method Updater_helper::arrayExtend() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Filename: updater/api.updater.php

Line Number: 109
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: Non-static method Updater_helper::getThirdPartyPath() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Filename: updater/api.updater.php

Line Number: 132
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: Non-static method Updater_helper::getThemePath() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Filename: updater/api.updater.php

Line Number: 133
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: Non-static method Updater_helper::getThirdPartyThemePath() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Filename: updater/api.updater.php

Line Number: 134
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/sites/v/v8a.2gc.org/public_html/_sitemanager/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 475
```

Comment: My guess is that the solution is the same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325781/expression-engine-module-devdemon-updater-displaying-php-errors-on-local-when